# How to merge 2 lists of dictionaries together and at the same time group by the same key

Tags: python, list, dictionary

My two dictionaries look like this

```
list1 = [{'time': '2020', 'name': 'one', 'address': '15423'},{'time': '2021', 'name': 'two', 'address': '8548305'}]
list2 = [{'to': '15423', 'value': '5'}, {'to': '8548305', 'value': '90'}, {'to': '123', 'value': '5'}]
```

I want my final list of dictionaries to look like this. Also, I don't want to consider dictionary if it doesn't have a match from another list of dictionaries

```
list3 = [{'time': '2020', 'name': 'one', 'address': '15423', 'value': '5'}, {'time': '2021', 'name': 'two', 'address': '8548305', 'value': '90'}]
```

Here is what I tried

```
[lst1.update(lst2) for lst1, lst2 in zip(list1, list2)]
```

But I don't know how can I group by address.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can do something like:

```
[{**lst1 , **lst2} for lst1 in list1 for lst2 in list2 if lst1["address"] == lst2["address"]]
```

##### Output

```
[{'address': '15423', 'name': 'one', 'time': '2020', 'value': '5'},
 {'address': '8548305', 'name': 'two', 'time': '2021', 'value': '90'}]
```

Note that, list comprehension might not be the best idea, since it lacks `break` and `continue` commands. Maybe it's more efficient to something like:

```py
for index,lst1 in enumerate(list1):
  for lst2 in list2:
    if lst2["address"] == lst1["address"]:
      list1[index]["value"] = lst2["value"]
      break
list1
```

##### Output

```
[{'address': '15423', 'name': 'one', 'time': '2020', 'value': '5'},
 {'address': '8548305', 'name': 'two', 'time': '2021', 'value': '90'}]
```